# Spring social Facebook Log in

Tags: spring, facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

i've been about 2/3 days reading the documentation of spring social. i barely used spring so i am kinda new on this. I would like to ask if someone could give me a short explanation of how i should configure the app(it alredy works via javascript, but not with Spring). The url that i allowed from the app's config is local.host:8080 which is the one i am using. Sometimes facebook tells me that the url of the app is not allowed, and sometimes it lets me log in and facebook tells me that the user dont have enough Permissions(i'm loggin in with the administrator account). I dont know if its mandatory to do this for just post on facebook.
Thanks you all for your time :l

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem just creating a new app and configuring it again :l